# Collection of objects from database

Tags: linq-to-sql, collections

Please help with my task.
I need to extract data from database and pack it in collection of object.

I try this code

```
DataClasses1DataCotext db = new DataClesses1DataContext();
IEnumerable<SimpleSMS> newSmses = db.SimpleSMS.GetEnumerator();
.....
```

but I haven't idea how to add filter (where db.SimpleSMS.Status = null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the LINQ query:

```
 IEnumerable<SimpleSMS> newSmses = (from pld in db.SimpleSMS                                                    
                              where pld.Status == null
                              select pld).GetEnumerator();
```

I hope it will help you.. :)

Comment: And can I do like this:                                            List<SimpleSMS> newSmses = (from pld in db.SimpleSMS                                                    
                              where pld.Status == null
                              select pld).ToList();                                      ??

Comment: yes, you can do it. This is very simple and also you can cast that list to type of object list. for eg: .ToList<SimpleSMS>();

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<SimpleSMS> newSmses = db.SimpleSMS.Where(s => s.Status == null).AsEnumerable();
```